# Query a document reference in mongodb if condition is met

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two mongo collections within my database named user and order. Within the user collection, there is an array of object references to orders. (the code snippet is a reduced down version of my schema for each collection).

```
    User ({
user_id
username
email
firstname
surname
...
orders : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ordersmodel"}]
})

Order ({
order_id
current_status
date_ordered
...
})
```

What I am looking to do is to access the order information for a specific user when passed a user_id. This was my thinking so far:

```
 User.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
    from: 'order',
    localfield: 'orders',
    foreignField: 'order_id',
    as: 'order'
        }},
        {
            $unwind: '$order'
        },
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            order_id: '$order.order_id', 
            status: '$order.status'
        }}
]).toArray();
```

and am not sure what to do next in order to return the orders for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `ref` in schema you can using [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) like this:

```
let result = await User.findById(user._id).populate("orders").lean()
console.log(result )
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to then access the values held by each order returned?

Comment: in option of populate you can filter the orders

Comment: Okay thank you. At the minute the result just returns the query rather than the data

Comment: can you show me the result and  which filed want to access?

Comment: Query {
  _mongooseOptions: { populate: { tickets: [PopulateOptions] } },
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
      capped: false,
      autoCreate: undefined,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
  And I'm just wanting to access the order status and order date